# Displaying Multiple Data-content on hover in angular

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I have a requirement in which when I hover on div two dates should display accordingly which I am fetching dynamically.

Below is the code I have written for hover effect:-

```
<a data-trigger="hover" title="Remarks" [attr.data-content]="data.timeline['Initial Site Measurement Request'].ideal | date:'dd/MM/yyyy - h:mm a',data.timeline['Initial Site Measurement Request'].ideal | date:'dd/MM/yyyy - h:mm a'" class="pop" (mouseenter)="openpopup($event)"><div *ngIf="data && data.timeline['Initial Site Measurement Request'].color !==null" style.background="{{data.timeline['Initial Site Measurement Request'].color}}" class="border_coloring" (click)="getNodeDetail(data.timeline['Initial Site Measurement Request'],'Initial Site Measurement Request',data)"></div></a>
```

But iIam getting error that , is not supported between [attr.data-content]

below is the error

```
Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
Parser Error: Unexpected token ',' at column 85 in [data.timeline['Initial Site Measurement Request'].ideal | date:'dd/MM/yyyy - h:mm a',data.timeline['Initial Site Measurement Request'].ideal | date:'dd/MM/yyyy - h:mm a'] in ng:///OrganisationModule/ZeroToFortyComponent.html@277:61 ("'dd/MM/yyyy - h:mm a'}}</div></td> -->
                <td ><a data-trigger="hover" title="Remarks" [ERROR ->][attr.data-content]="data.timeline['Initial Site Measurement Request'].ideal | date:'dd/MM/yyyy - h:m"):
```

If trying with single value inside data-content it is working fine but my requirement is i have to show 3 values there.

Please tell me how can i achieve this.

Comment: Can you add the full HTML file? It seems there is a syntax issue.

Comment: Browser is giving error on [attr.data-content], as i have no idea how to display multiple value inside data-content attribute

Comment: Can you show what the expected outcome should look like (versus the output you get when just using the single value)?

Comment: when hovering on div, I want to show 3 different dates which i am not able to achieve with this attr.data-content right now.
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/bootstrap-4-popover/
This is what i am using but i want to render dates dynamically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `data-content` attribute expects a single string. Instead of trying to provide multiple values, simply combine all your values into one string. The bootstrap popover can also render html tags, so you can freely structure and style your content. To enable html tags, you have to add the attribute `data-html="true"`.

```
[attr.data-content]="'<div>' + (data.timeline['Initial Site Measurement Request'].ideal | date:'dd/MM/yyyy - h:mm a') + '</div><div>' + (data.timeline['Initial Site Measurement Request'].ideal | date:'dd/MM/yyyy - h:mm a') + '</div>'"
```

Comment: it is woking fine and thanks for your time . But the only problem is it is displaying div also.

Comment: Try this instead `data-content="<div>{{ data.timeline['Initial Site Measurement Request'].ideal | date:'dd/MM/yyyy - h:mm a') }}</div>"`

Comment: [attr.data-content]="<div>{{data.timeline['Initial Site Measurement Request'].ideal | date:'dd/MM/yyyy - h:mm a'}}</div> +<div>{{data.timeline['Initial Site Measurement Request'].ideal | date:'dd/MM/yyyy - h:mm a'}}</div> + <div>{{data.timeline['Initial Site Measurement Request'].ideal | date:'dd/MM/yyyy - h:mm a'}}</div>"
this is how i try to eimplement it for 3 dates, it is giving error here

Comment: You have to change `[attr.data-content]` to just `data-content`. And you can also remove the `+` between the `div` tags.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that you have to add the attribute `data-html="true"` for html tags to render. I edited the answer.

Comment: How can I add ngIf condition in these div inside these data-content ? Any suggestions are welcome

Comment: The simplest solution is probably to bind to a function like `[attr.data-content]="getPopover()"` where you return your content based on your conditions. However, I would suggest using [ngx-bootstrap](https://github.com/valor-software/ngx-bootstrap) for Angular + Bootstrap.